# Cocos2dx - RenderTexture tiles stretched after repeated visits

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I have built a coloring book app for the iOS platform in the first place having in mind to build it for other platforms also. Anyway, my algorithm implies repeated visits of the resulting sprite of the RenderTexture. 
So besides other sprites that call the visit method, I need to call again the resulting one, something like:

```
renderTexture->beginWithClear(148, 217, 249, 255);
renderTexture->getSprite()->setPosition( /*computed position*/);
renderTexture->getSprite()->visit();
//draw other elements by calling their visit() method
renderTexture->end()
```

The problem is the resulting quality. More exactly, it seems that the rendering is performed with tiles and there is some stretching visible after each render step. Please find attached screenshot I made showing what I mean:

[screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8tb1wnh3t56st6v/IMG_0095.jpg?dl=0)

This can be reproducible by presenting the scene with the source codes from the following archive: [archive](https://www.dropbox.com/s/11vfkjihm1qtb2a/Archive.zip?dl=0)

I have provided all the details also to Cocos2d-x issue tracking environment but didn't received any feedback.

If anyone reproduced this issue and found a solution, please share it. Thank you!

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem? Transitions also have visual glitches because of this bug.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still stuck :(. I didn't find a solution for this and for some reasons the Cocos-2dx guys are avoiding to handle this issue. Maybe it can have other implications, but who knows.